# Node Js code to replace words with integers from 0-9

Tags: node.js

**My Code is this:**

```
var obj = { 'one ': '1 ', 'two ': '2 ', 'three ': '3 ', 'four ': '4 ', 'five ': '5 ', 'six ': '6 ', 'seven ': '7 ', 'eight ': '8 ', 'nine ': '9 ', 'zero ': '0 ',
  ' one': '1 ', ' two': '2 ', ' three': '3 ', ' four': '4 ', ' five': '5 ', ' six': '6 ', ' seven': '7 ', ' eight': '8 ', ' nine': '9 ', ' zero': '0 ',
};


var str = 'the store number is one two three four'
//Checking if the string has any numbers in words..
if(str.indexOf('one') > -1 || str.indexOf('two') > -1 || str.indexOf('three') > -1 || str.indexOf('four') > -1 || str.indexOf('five') > -1
|| str.indexOf('six') > -1 || str.indexOf('seven') > -1 || str.indexOf('eight') > -1 || str.indexOf('nine') > -1 || str.indexOf('zero') > -1) {
  str = str + ' ';
  //Looping each word in the array and replacing the number word in the string with the respective number
  for(var i in obj) {
    if (str.indexOf(i) !== -1){
     str = str.replace(i, obj[i])
      //console.log (i, obj[i])
     }

  }
console.log(str)
}
```

My task is to first check the string if it has any numbers in words from 0-9 (say 'zero', 'one', 'two' ... 'nine'). If found any then i have to replace it with their respective integer values as '0','1'..

**Input:** "the store is one two three four"
after conversion should be:
**Output:** "the store is 1 2 3 4"

The above code does the job. But can i get a compressed code with regex or something?

Comment: Why do you have the extra spaces after each word (e.g.`'one '`) ? further, you've entered all the digits twice - no need for that. You want a "compressed code" ? remove both `if` conditions - they're not needed.

Comment: If not, input like 'oneself' will be replaced as '1self'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question has two redundant `if` conditions, it can be simplified to:

```
var obj = { 'one ': '1 ', 'two ': '2 ', 'three ': '3 ', 'four ': '4 ', 'five ': '5 ', 'six ': '6 ', 'seven ': '7 ', 'eight ': '8 ', 'nine ': '9 ', 'zero ': '0 '};

var str = 'the store number is one two three four '; // if we don't add a space after the 'four' - it will not be replaced!
for(var i in obj) {
    while (str.indexOf(i) > -1) {
        str = str.replace(i, obj[i]);
    }
}
console.log(str); // the store number is 1 2 3 4
```

And no, regex will *not* make this code more concise!

Comment: `var str = 'the store number is one two three four one';`

Comment: @TuanAnhTran good point, one additional line of code fixes it :)

Comment: If i don't add space, input like 'oneself' will be replaced as '1self', which should not happen...

Comment: @ChrisPioline and how will you get over the "last word" problem?

Comment: @ChrisPioline in that . case - I think that this solution should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a big benefit in using regex here. This seems to call for a simple string replace using static, known values.

Maybe something like this

```
var str = 'the store number is one two three four'
var strArray = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']

strArray.forEach(function(thisStr) {
    if (str.toLowerCase().includes(thisStr)) {
        console.log("String includes " + thisStr);
    }
});

str = str.replace('zero','0').replace('one','1').replace('two','2').replace('three','3').replace('four','4').replace('five','5').replace('six','6').replace('seven','7').replace('eight','8').replace('nine','9');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

```
'use strict';

const maps = [
    ['one', '1'],
    ['two', '2'],
    ['three', '3'],
    ['four', '4'],
    ['five', '5'],
    ['six', '6']
];

function convert(input) {
    if (typeof input !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError(`Expected a string, got ${typeof input}`);
    }

    return maps.reduce((seed, map) => {
        input = input.replace(new RegExp(map[0], 'g'), map[1]);
        return input;
    }, input);
};


var str = 'the store number is one two three four'
console.log(convert(str));
```

Output

```
the store number is 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Congrats, you successfully took a simple code and made it more complex...

Comment: It's JavaScript dude!!